# How to create Azure Windows VM using Terraform?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, terraform-provider-azure, azure-virtual-network

I have environment in Azure with VNet configuration and resources.
I wanto automate the deployment of Azure Windows VM with existing vnet configuration using Terraform.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Could you share the terraform code here?

Answer (score 0):

Firstofall, if you use the existing vnet configuration in the terraform code, it will throw the error code: **"Resource already exists"**.  To resolve this, one can run `terraform import` to import this resource into the **"terraform state file"** and let terraform import it into the current executable file.

[image]

[terraform import from terraform registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_network#import):

```bash
terraform import azurerm_virtual_network.existing /subscriptions/<subscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<resourcegroup>/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/<vnet>
```

[image]

***When trying to deploy existing resources in Terraform, you should include a data block. Check the complete script below for your issue, and it was successfully deployed as follows.***

```bash
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "existing"{
name = "jahnavivnet"
resource_group_name = "example-resources"
} 
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "existing" {
  name                = "jahnavivnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  resource_group_name = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "existing" {
  name                 = "default"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.existing.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  name                = "NICxxx"
  location            = "West Europe"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "default"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.existing.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                = "xxxxxnameofVM"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  size                = "Standard_F2"
  admin_username      = "user"
  admin_password      = "xxxx"
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.example.id,
  ]

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2019-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}
```

***Executed*** `terraform init`:

[image]

***Executed*** `terraform plan`:

[image]

***Executed*** `terraform apply --auto-approve`:

[image]

***Deployed virtual machine with the existing virtual network configuration.***

[image]

*Refer* [terraform templates](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_virtual_machine).